# MSI setup is no longer supported in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, windows-installer

As announced in this blog:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx
MSI setup (.vdproj) is no longer supported in VS2012.
I need to create a setup compatible for both the version of VS, 2010 and 2012.
InstallShield and Wix are external solution and the learning curve seems to be insane, so:
is there a better way to do so easly?

Comment: The underlying complexity of MSI was always there, VDPROJ just hid most of it. Setup is an important specialty and it will be very rewarding if you dedicate the time to learn it.

Comment: You might find [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) more to your liking. I find it simpler than WiX, though similarly powerful. But learning WiX might be a good investment of your time.

Answer (score 0):

Another free alternative is [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com), product on which I am a developer, it has an [extension for VS 2010 and 2012](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/ai-ext-vs.html), and very soon will have one for 2013.

Its completely GUI based, so you will get the hang of it very easy. [The tutorials](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorials.html) available on the website can also help you can get started easily.